# a huge leaflet data with nodejs/mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

how can I use a huge JSON data from leaflet with Rest API (node js /MongoDB)?
I need to use this data in my app:
URL=>
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson/master/regions/nouvelle-aquitaine/communes-nouvelle-aquitaine.geojson

I use the package: stream-JSON but I didn't find how can I use it, is there any solution or strategy for consuming big JSON data from this URL

Comment: Can you explain what the end result looks like?   Running `curl` on that URL yields a big but proper GeoJSON file that renders nicely at geojson.io.   Are you asking how to store this in mongodb?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti when I create a file in my client-app and access it to display data on leaflet cart the client side still load..so I think that's should store data in MongoDB base and send data from my server-app(node/MongoDB) to client-app and that's why I use some package but I don't find a solution

Comment: This question is too broad.   Yes, in general MongoDB is great for storing and quickly vending GeoJSON data.   The question , it seems, is seeking a comprehensive design and implementation.